# View didn't up by keyboard on second click into text field

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift4

I have an iOS app with login screen(mobile and password). Let's imagine a case:

1. User tap the phone number text field and number keyboard appears, view is up with keyboard.
2. User fill phone number and tap password text field, keyboard changes from number layout yo standard.
3. User tap Return button on keyboard, and keyboard dismiss, view is down.
4. User tap phone number text field or password on more time for data correction

And at stage 4 the keyboard appear, BUT view is not up anymore, and when I tap return button on keyboard, the view drop even down with black line on top of screen. How I can fix that problem? in code I have this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

and

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height/3
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height/3
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height/3
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the IQKeyboardmanager.It will take care of these things automatically
GitHub link - [IQKeyboardManger](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)